# special character wpf

Tags: wpf, special-characters

a simple WPF question. 
I would like to have a button with content="<" (the "backward button")
How to I achieve this because the following is wrong:

```
Content="<"
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
<Button Content="&lt;"/>
```

Remember that XAML is still XML, so the same escapes apply.

This is also what the compiler tells you in that case, at least it does for me:

> The open angle bracket character `'<'` is not valid in an attribute. It should be written as `'&lt;'`.

Answer (score 5):

try this :

```
Content = "&lt;"
```

Answer (score 5):

[this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748250.aspx) should help, basically you need to use

```
    <Button Content="&lt;" />
```

Answer (score -1):

if you search a list of this codes, they are alled ISO codes

Comment: No, those are XML character references.